# HTML/JS shape subtraction

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, shapes

Is there a way in HTML5/JS to create a composite shape that is, for example, a polygon subtracted from an enclosing rectangle? The intent would be to have an opaque fill to the composite shape but have the inside of the polygon be transparent.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can even use *fill-rule* to do this without the need of compositing.

Canvas supports two fill-rules, the default [non-zero winding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) as well as the [even-odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) rule (see links for details).

By using the latter each line is scanned internally and number of intersections are counted. The segment between an odd and even boundary is then filled, which in this case allows us to encapsulate a polygon inside another and only have the space between them filled.

[image: result]

#### Example code using fill-rule

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// enclosing rectangle
ctx.rect(10, 10, 280, 130);

// some interior shape inside
ctx.rotate(0.2);
ctx.rect(60, 20, 200, 50);

ctx.fill("evenodd");
```

```css
body {background:#ddd}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

And of course, composition is also possible but this will require a "blank sheet" to start with as it depends on the alpha channel.

Draw first shape the normal way using "source-over" composition mode. Then switch to "destination-out" which will remove any existing non-transparent pixels based on the pixels in the new drawing. In this case it will use the new shape to punch a hole in the previous shape.

#### Example code using compositing

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// enclosing rectangle
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 130);

// some interior shape inside
ctx.rotate(0.2);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";  // will "punch-out" background
ctx.fillRect(60, 20, 200, 50);
```

```css
body {background:#ddd}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Clever answer using the `even-odd winding rule` to isolate `A && !B` -- upvote. :-)